# concatMap() equivalent but async like in mergeMap()

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an observable `myObservable` :

```
let myObservable = Observable.of(2000, 1000)
```

With `concatMap()` : TOTAL TIME = 3000 millis, results in the original order.

```
myObservable.concatMap(v => Rx.Observable.of(v).delay(v))
// concatMap: 2000, concatMap: 1000
```

With `mergeMap()` : TOTAL TIME = 2000 millis, results not in the original order.

```
myObservable.mergeMap(v => Rx.Observable.of(v).delay(v))
// mergeMap: 1000, mergeMap: 2000
```

I want a way to get the results in the original order like in `concatMap`, but calling each nested observable asynchronously instead of waiting for the next nested observable to complete :

```
// --- The behavior that I want ---
myObservable.myCustomMap(v => Rx.Observable.of(v).delay(v))
// myCustomMap: 2000, myCustomMap: 1000
// TOTAL TIME = 2000 millis
```

Is there an elegant solution?

**Edit** :  I am looking for a solution that also works if the source (`myObservable`) is asynchronous, not only for this particular synchronous case.

Comment: You should use `forkJoin` for that. Writting a proper answer.

Comment: Do you expect the source `myObservable` to emit asynchronously? I mean is the usecase is more complicated than just `Observable.of(2000, 1000)`?

Comment: @martin Yes the usecase is more complicated and potentially asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

You should use `forkJoin` for firing all the observables at the same time.

Here's an example without comments:

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

const obs$ = Observable
  .of(3000, 3000, 1000)
  .map(x => Observable.of(x).delay(x));

const allObsWithDelay$ = obs$.toArray();

const result$ = allObsWithDelay$
  .switchMap(arr => Observable.forkJoin(arr));

result$
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

And the same with explanation:

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

// source observable, emitting simple values...
const obs$ = Observable
  .of(3000, 3000, 1000)
  // ... which are wrapped into a different observable and delayed
  .map(x => Observable.of(x).delay(x));

// use a reduce to build an array containing all the observables
const allObsWithDelay$ = obs$.toArray();

const result$ = allObsWithDelay$
  // when we receive the array with all the observable
  // (so we get one event, with an array of multiple observables)
  .switchMap(arr =>

    // launch every observable into this array at the same time
    Observable.forkJoin(arr)
  );

// display the result
result$
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

With those values: `3000, 3000, 1000` the whole process is taking 3 seconds (the maximum of them as they're fired at the same time)

**Working Plunkr:** https://plnkr.co/edit/IRgEhdjCmZSTc6hSaVeF?p=preview

Edit 1: Thanks to [@PierreCitror](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2686744/perriercitror) for pointing out `toArray` which is better than `scan` :)

Comment: Nice Maxime,  you can simplify the reduce by calling toArray() instead

Comment: Riiiiiiight this is what I've been looking for but couldn't remember, thx @PerrierCitror :D

Comment: Well, I'm not sure this is exactly what OP is looking for. If `obs$` is asynchronous then `switchMap` will make all Observables unsubscribe and subscribe again. For example when you have 5 remote calls and `obs$` emits a 6th one then all previous 5 will repeat.

Comment: Indeed in my usecase this solution actually doesn't work. I wanted to make a simple example to explain my problem clearly, but it oversimplified my problem. You are welcome to bring a more general solution @martin

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
myObservable
  .mergeMap((val, i) => Observable.forkJoin(
    Observable.of(i),
    Observable.of(v).delay(v)
  ))
  .scan((acc, ([i, result])) => {
    acc[i] = result;
    return acc;
  }, {})
  .filter(allResults => {
    // Whatever goes here
    Object.keys(allResults) // list indices of all finished responses 
  })
```

This will accumulate all responses in a single object where each response is assigned an index at which it arrived into `mergeMap`.

Then in `filter` you can write whatever logic you want that decides whether the current state should be propagated further (eg. you can wait until a certain number of responses arrived or whatever).